# How can I make a button element that is inside a gridview take up the full size of the column in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, gridview

I am carrying out a project in visual studio 2019 using C# language, the project is for Android, and I have the following dilemma: I have a listview in which I show some data, it contains a gridview with two columns to organize it, the truth is I want to align the values ​​to the left, but when I set the component to the HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" property, it aligns to the left but does not occupy the full width of the column. If I remove that property then it By default it aligns me to the middle and if it takes the width of the column, here I send you my code in xaml and an image of how it is now with the horizontal option property in startandspan
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6Ks7.jpg)

that its my code in xaml

```
<Frame Grid.Row="1"
                       Grid.Column="0" 
                       Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                       BorderColor="Black"                                                               
                       CornerRadius="5" 
                       x:Name="frmresultados"
                       BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke"  >                                                 
                              
                    <control:AutoScrollListView x:Name="lstpedidos" 
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Pedidos}"
                                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Always"
                                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always" 
                                      SeparatorColor="#1c1c1c"
                                      >
                            
                            <control:AutoScrollListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <Grid RowDefinitions="*,Auto" ColumnDefinitions="50,*"
                                          ColumnSpacing="1" 
                                          >

                                            <Button        x:Name="lblcantidad"
                                                           Text="{Binding CantidadArt}"
                                                           TextColor="White"
                                                           BackgroundColor="Blue"
                                                           FontSize="15" 
                                                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                                                           Grid.Row="0"
                                                           Grid.Column="0"
                                                           Margin="0,3,3,0"
                                                           HorizontalOptions="Start"                                                           
                                                           Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.CambiarUnidadCommand,Source={x:Reference lstpedidos}}" 
                                                           CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                                       
                                                            >
                                                
                                                     
                                            </Button>


                                            <Button        x:Name="lbldescripcion"
                                                           Text="{Binding DescripcionArt}"
                                                           TextColor="White"
                                                           FontSize="15"
                                                           BackgroundColor="Blue"
                                                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                                                           Grid.Row="0"
                                                           Grid.Column="1"
                                                           Margin="0,3,3,0"
                                                           HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                                           >
                                            </Button>



                                        </Grid>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </control:AutoScrollListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </control:AutoScrollListView>
                </Frame>
```

Comment: If the button element has a width property and the column has a width property, you can set the button's property equal to the column property.

Comment: Instead of setting the HorizontalOptions property on individual buttons, you could try setting the HorizontalOptions property on the entire grid to control the alignment of all elements within it.